# Laravel Spatie Permission does not redirect not authorized user to login page

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am using `spatie/laravel-permission`, When not authorized users view private page, laravel shows 403 error but I want `laravel` redirects them to `login page` and after login automatically redirect to private page.

For example not authorized user wants to go /admin .i want redirect him to /login page after successfully login redirect him to /admin.

**Laravel Version** :  `5.7`

Comment: Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so that you may add something more valuable to your question in-order for someone to help you out.

Comment: Sounds like you need a middleware? But your last sentence doesn't make much sense. Please post what you have tried.

Comment: here is the tutorial. may be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlGu2pa1bdU&list=PL0wCC44AhrC2vtrBcCmEmfjvFVk1RROFa&index=2

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of user permissions. If a user cannot do an action based on their permission level that means the user is already signed in. The behaviour you want is already part of the normal `auth` middleware that you should also be using on the admin route

Answer (score 4):

based on the `spatie/laravel-permission` docs you can see that it throws some specific exceptions that you can handle inside your code. here you can find all the exceptions. [link](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/tree/master/src/Exceptions)

so based on your question you need to handle `UnauthorizedException`

inside your `app/Exceptions/Handler` add this code :

```
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (\Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException $e, $request) {
        return response()->json([
            'responseMessage' => 'You do not have the required authorization.',
            'responseStatus'  => 403,
        ]);
    });
}
```

this will return a JSON response,if you want to return the user to the login page you can change it to this:

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```